# How to place the first name last name on top of the textbox as in the picture

Tags: javascript, asp.net, css, asp.net-mvc

I have seen it but I am not sure how to do it.. or what is used to wrap around textbox to accomplish this.

I thought it would be done with field set but I could be wrong.

I have included an image and hope that convey my point.

Thank you .. 
[image]

Comment: I think it may be possible by using a web user control if not then you should try a custom server control.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here

```
<div class="section">
    <div class="left">
        Name
    </div>
    <div class="right">
        <div class="nm">
            First
        </div>
        <div class="val">
            <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtBox1"></asp:TextBox>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="right">
        <div class="nm">
            Last
        </div>
        <div class="val">
            <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtBox2"></asp:TextBox>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Style:

```
<style>
    .section
    {
        clear: both;
        }
        .section .left
        {
            float: left;
            font-size: 25px;
            padding:5px;
            padding-top:15px;

        }
        .section .right
        {
            float: left;
            padding:5px;

            }
            .section .right .nm
            {
                font-size: 10px;
            }
            .section .right .val
            {
            }
</style>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way of doing this without tables.

CSS:

```
<style>
div{
width:150px
}
div label{
clear:left;
font-size:9px;
}
</style>
```

And the HTML:

```
<div><label>First</label><input type="text" id="firstName" /></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Someone will probably shoot me for this, but a table can make this pretty easy..

```
<table style="width:375px;" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="2">
    <col width="75px">
    <col width="150px">
    <col width="150px">
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td>first</td>
        <td>last</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            NAME
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" id="firstName" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" id="lastName" />
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I can whip one up using `<divs>`  if you would like as well..

EDIT: I am not familiar with any .NET Controller out there that would do this automatically, unless it were custom..

Comment: I knew that method, I was wondering if there is a better way to do this.. I do not think it is another td instead they using something else.

Comment: After I saw Waqar's comment, I realized what you might have meant.. That I am not sure of, sorry :(

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

```
<table>
       <tr>
          <td>
             Name
          </td>
          <td>
             Html.LabelFor(m => m.First)
             Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.First)
          </td>
          <td>
             Html.LabelFor(m => m.Last)
             Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Last)
          </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
```